# Button color error

Tags: css

I'm new with CSS. Here is the CSS for my button, but I need it to be very similar to the button in the picture without the green background. I have some problems with colors if you can help i will be very thankful.

```css
.button {
  background-color:#333;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: -5px 0 0 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  align-items:center;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border:1px solid #333;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 5px 3px 2px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 5px 3px 2px #333;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 3px 2px #333;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Access our old platform</button>
```

[image: Image of button without the background]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    button {
    background-color:#333;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    padding: 18px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: -5px 0 0 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    align-items:center;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 3px 2px #333;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <button classname="button">Access our old platform</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.button {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #55585e 0%,#28343b 100%);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Access our old platform</button>
```